# Because of `strictNullChecks` return type of function is `<type> | undefined` although it will never be undefined

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

The function is as follows:

```js
const getProp = <
  TObj extends object,
  TKey extends keyof TObj
>(props: TObj, key: TKey, def: TObj[TKey]): TObj[TKey] => {
  if (props[key] == null) return def
  return props[key]
}
```

When used as follows:

```js
const fluid = getProp(props, 'fluid', true) // return type is boolean | undefined
```

The return type is `boolean | undefined` although I'd expect and need it to be `boolean`.

Comment: Can you give a [mre] - what's the type of `props`? Presumably `fluid` is optional in it, hence `TObj[TKey]` is `boolean | undefined`: https://tsplay.dev/NDP9VN.

Comment: `props` can be any object and `fluid` is indeed optional. Nevertheless, the function checks if `props['fluid']` is null, so it I would expect TS to know that it can't return undefined?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The function is implemented this way to prevent the return of undefined or null and requires a default value to do so.

Comment: But the return type of your function is **still `TObj[TKey]`**. So from the caller's perspective, that's what it gets; even if the compiler _can_ work out that the value would never be undefined or null, what it checks is that it's compatible with the return value that could be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are correct, following your comment I was just thinking about the `Required` utility type, added that on the return type and that fixed it!